# Parent is getting executed at last

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml

My project structure:

`src
 --pom.xml
module1
 --pom.xml`

In source pom, i have defined one property by name MY_VERSION whose value is used as version for parent in module1 pom.

Module 1 pom looks like below:

```
<parent>xyz</parent>
<version>${MY_VERSION}</version>
 ....
```

Now the reactor order is as follows:

```
module1
parent
```

I want reactor order to be:

```
parent
module1
```

Comment: Which maven version do you use? How do you call Maven?

Comment: mvn install -pMy_profile

Comment: Why using a profile? Why do you like to have the reator order changed...this is done by maven on it's own..by using the dependencies...?

Comment: You're doing something. Please tell us what exactly you want to do, why do you want the reactor to have a specific order. Let Maven handle that, why do you even worry?

Comment: in my_profile i do some work which is required by child modules. So it is imp for me to execute parent first. If i remove $MY_VERSION from child module's pom, and instead use hard coded version like 1.0.0.0, then it works fine.

Comment: The reactor order change if we use variable $MY_VERSION in child pom for declaring its parent version. It has nothing to do with profile execution.